# remove a blank option of select field that was generated by SimpleForm

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this piece of code:

```
= f.input :category, :as => :select, :label => false, :collection => Choices["Categories"]
```

Choices["Categories"] is just a hash of key=>value pairs.

SimpleForm generates a select field with all needed options, but it also makes the first option blank.
 This blank option is present in all select fields that were generated by SimpleForm.

But I don't want to have a blank option. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Something like `:allow_blank_option => false`?

I tried to make a presence validation of this attribute hoping that SimpleForm will detect it, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can pass a `include_blank: false, include_hidden: false` option:

```
= f.input :category, :as => :select, :label => false, :collection => Choices["Categories"], include_blank: false, include_hidden: false
```

Comment: @rony36 it works if you use `include_blank: true`, then user will be able to deselect all and select blank.

Answer (score 2):

or you can customize call back action in your model to remove any empty string in the array parameter, assuming a parameter with the name "types":

```
before_validation :remove_empty_string

def remove_empty_string
  types.reject! { |l| l.empty? }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a blank field from select it is necessary to show the selected so add `selected: 1`
Then set prompt to anything like `prompt: "Please Select"`
The final output will be 
`<%= select("social_links",:option_id, Option.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },{ selected: 1 , prompt: "Please Select"}, { class: 'form-control' , required:true})%>`