# rails simple_form prevent select adding a blank by default to collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm rendering an array of strings using collections in `simple-form` gem, I've [gone through this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143306/remove-a-blank-option-of-select-field-that-was-generated-by-simpleform), but the solutions there did not work well.

here's the Tag

```
<%= f.input :training_modes, collection: get_training_modes, include_blank: false, input_html: { multiple: true } %>
```

But when I save through this select I get arrays like these

```
["", "Instructor Led Training", "Webex"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass `include_hidden: false` option with the select to remove the hidden field

```
<%= f.input :training_modes, collection: get_training_modes, include_blank: false, include_hidden: false, input_html: { multiple: true } %>
```

Hope that helps!